# How to get domain extension from URL with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I'm trying to get domain extension from a URL with jQuery. But not sure how to cover all possible scenarios. Highlighted the parts I need to get from the URL;

```
https://www.amazon.**com**/dp/067144901X
https://www.amazon.**co.uk**/dp/067144901X
https://www.amazon.**it**/dp/067144901X
https://www.amazon.**de**/dp/067144901X
```

```js
$(".get").on('click', function(event) {
  var DomainEX = $('#url').val();
  alert(DomainEX);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="url">
<button class="get">GET</button>
```

Comment: Its bit of a slippery slope since `.co`, `.in` and `.co.in`, all three can exist in a URL, which makes it harder to identify. I would suggest you use some library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/tld-extract for this rather writing your own logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to extract parts from an URL the **[URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)** might come handy. In your case the `url.hostname` but this returns all the parts of a domain (including subdomain and extension).

For **your specific case** you could use a bit of regex:

```js
const getAmazonExt = url => /amazon.([^/]+)/.exec(url)[1];

 
console.log(getAmazonExt('https://www.amazon.com/dp/067144901X'))
console.log(getAmazonExt('https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/067144901X'))
console.log(getAmazonExt('https://www.amazon.it/dp/067144901X'))
console.log(getAmazonExt('https://www.amazon.de/dp/067144901X'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to URL, get the host name:

`const hostName = (new URL('https://www.amazon.com/dp/067144901X')).hostname;`

Then extract everything that is after the site name:

`const extension = hostName.split('amazon').pop()`

```js
//https://www.amazon.com/dp/067144901X
//https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/067144901X

function getDomainExtension(url, siteName) {

  const hostName = (new URL(url)).hostname;
  const extension = hostName.split(siteName).pop()
  console.log(hostName)

  return extension;
}


$(".get").on('click', function(event) {
  var DomainEX = $('#url').val();
  const extension = getDomainExtension(DomainEX, 'amazon')
  console.log(extension)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="url">
<button class="get">GET</button>
```